# Tableau Aggregate Percentage

Tags: aggregate-functions, percentage, tableau-api

I am trying to remove the duplicate percentages here as my client is looking to see when the change stops. The data is correct in this view I just need to eliminate the duplicate percentages. So for example on the last line I should only see the data for 0-7 as the data for

8-14 has not really changed. for 10/18 I should see 25.75 and 31.93 and that's it. The date pulling the percentage is just a field summed. Any ideas? I am very new to Tableau and have been researching for a few now.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data? Are the ages (I assume the ones on the top are age ranges) in the data already or are these bins you created?

Comment: I created the age buckets in the SQL behind the data. I have attached a sample set of data.

Comment: seems like somethign went wrong with the data sample.

Answer (score 1):

I send to you a sample with Running Total table calculation. I suppose is closed to your approach.

This is a regular running total:

[image]

You should click on your measure, then on "**Edit table calculation**" and finally on "**customize...**" and filter, for example, to cells with values:

[image]

This will convert your running total in a calculated field. You can rename it.